# data urls / content filtering

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I would like to prevent my users from pasting embedded Images into the Editor.

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw...g==" alt="Red dot" />
```

After checking the Manual, I realized there are filters for element attributes.

However, I was not able to find anything about filtering values of an Attribute like the src Attribute of an img element.

I would appreciate if someone would point me to the right direction.

Cheers,

Oliver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Advanced Content Filtering for that. You can easily block content with [`config.disallowedContent`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-disallowedContent) config option.

```
config.disallowedContent = {
    img: {
        match: function( element ) {
            if ( element.name === 'img' && element.attributes.src && String( element.attributes.src ).match( /^data\:/ ) ) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
};
```

For more information check out:

- [Disallowed Content](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_disallowed_content) guide,
- [Advanced Content Filter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter) guide